Let $X$ be a random variable with cdf $F$ and pmf $p$. Show that if either of the images of $X$, $F$, or $p$ is countable, so are the two others.
I am trying to prove the result (?) below. I believe I may have proved that $(1\iff 3)$, but I'm struggling to show that $(2)$ implies (or is implied) by either of the other two conditions:
Let $X$ be a random variable with cdf $F$ and pmf $p$. The following are equivalent:

$\text{im}(X)$ is countable.
$\text{im}(F)$ is countable.
$\text{im}(p)$ is countable.


My attempt: to show that $(1\implies 3)$, note that $p(x) = P(X=x) > 0$ for at most countably many $x\in\mathbb{R}$, but
$$\text{im}(p) = \{0\}\cup\bigcup_{p(x)>0} p(x)$$
which must therefore be countable. To show $(3\implies 1)$, let $\text{im}(p)=\{y_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$. Note either $y_k = 0$, or $p^{-1}(y_k)$ is finite, as otherwise
$$P(X \in p^{-1}(y_k)) = \sum_{x\in p^{-1}(y_k)}P(X = x) = \sum_{p(x) = y_k}p(x) = \infty,$$
which is impossible. Thus
$$\text{im}(X) \leq \text{im}(p)\cdot\mathbb{N} \leq \mathbb{N}.$$

What are $\mathsf{im}(X)$ and $\mathsf{im}(F)$? I suppose $p$ is defined as $p(x) = \mathbf{P}(X = x).$

@WilliamM. they are the images of $X$ and $F$ respectively, and $p$ is indeed defined like so.

You didn't answer my question.

If $X$ takes countable, $X\in{a_1,a_2,\dots}$, then it's a discrete random variable with p.m.f. which has finitely many values, and cdf $F$ is  a step function with the same values; $F(x)=\sum_{i:a_i\le x} \mathbb{P}(X=a_i)$. The opposite is true as well. However, you cannot define $p$ unless $X$ is discrete.

There's a rule I think relating a discrete random variable to a random variable with countable range...when you say pmf $p$ you mean $X$ is discrete right?

@WilliamM. I do not understand what your question is then

@Sam what are the mathematical definitions of the images of $X$ and $F$? Both $X$ and $F$ are functions and if you take the usual definition of the image of a function, the result is false (at least for $X$).
